# It is normal to an infinite loop within the OnPaint event of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#-2.0

I have the following code:

```
int a = 0;
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {

       base.OnPaint(e);         


        this.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = a += 1;
    }
```

and I can see that the variable increases to infinity. I'm using it to paint a graphic making an instance of it and it works fine.
Is this normal? I am creating infinite graph instance? Or I have a problem and I don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the value, the grid needs to re-`Paint` itself., thus firing the `Paint` event again and re-executing your code.
This behavior is by design.

In general, you should never change external state in a `Paint` handler; drawing code should be idempotent (other than the provided `Graphics`).
`Paint` events are unpredicable and will fire very often.